# javascript function not working in IE 7

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone please tell me how do I make this script run in IE 7? When I run this , nothing happens.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function moveSelectedOption() {
        // Fetch references to the <select> elements.
        var origin = document.getElementById('origin_select');
        var target = document.getElementById('target_select');


        // Fetch the selected option and clone it.
        var option = origin.options[origin.selectedIndex];

       var copy = option.cloneNode(true);

        // Add the clone to the target element.
        target.add(copy, null);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="origin_select" multiple>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
    <select id="target_select" multiple>

        <option value="C1">C1</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="moveSelectedOption()">Add</button>
 <!--   <input type="button" onClick="moveSelectedOption()" value="AddMeToo" />  this does not work either-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "Nothing" very rarely happens. Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var origin = document.getElementById('origin_select');
var target = document.getElementById('target_select');

// Fetch the selected option and clone it.
var option = origin.options[origin.selectedIndex];
target.options[target.options.length] = new Option(option.text, option.value);
```

If you want to remove the option from the origin select element then you can use this

```
origin.remove(option);
```

**[Demo without move](http://jsbin.com/eqosa/2)**

**[Demo with move](http://jsbin.com/eqosa)**

***Edit***

This line was causing the error.

```
target.add(copy, null);
```

> add() does not work with the standard
>   second argument in Explorer, even with
>   value null, so in order to be
>   compatible one may try the
>   two-argument version and upon failure,
>   use the single argument version.

See **[select.add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/select.add)**

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Can you please tell me what was the problem with my version?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can't use `add(option, null)` in IE-up-to-7 due to a bug (you get “Type mismatch”). You would have to use `add(option)`, but of course that's non-standard and breaks elsewhere. So to be safe, use `select.add(option, options.length)`, or `select.options[options.length]= option`.

Next, you can't add an option to a select when that option has already been in a select in IE-up-to-7 (even after cloning!) due to another bug (you get “Invalid argument”). IE's handling of `<option>` elements is off in a lot of ways, the source of which is that IE's select boxes are native Windows widgets, not objects implemented by the browser. Consequently IE's HTMLOptionElement interface is only a façade, that often slips.

The safe way to handle option elements is to create them anew each time, either using `document.createElement` and writing the `value` and `text` properties, or using the old-school `new Option()` constructor as in rahul's answer.

Finally, you shouldn't use `selectedIndex` on a `<select multiple>`. Since there isn't necessarily one-and-only-one selection it doesn't make sense in any browser. (For example, clicking the `Add` button with no selection gives an error.) Instead, loop over all options and copy each option that is `.selected`.